Scheduled job getting triggered but no traces after 2 lines
I have a scheduled job running on my Sitecore 10.3.2 CM.
The code getting triggered is as below:
  public void RebuildDB(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item[] itemarray, CommandItem commandItem, ScheduleItem scheduleItem)
        {
            Log.Info("LinkDBRebuild job triggered from custom code.", this);

            try
            {
                string envName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["localenv:define"];
                string envRole = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["role:define"];
                Log.Info("LinkDBRebuild job triggered from custom code. Details: Env:" + envName + " Role: " + envRole, this);
                if (
                    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(envName) && envName.Equals(Constants.Environment.ProductionEnvironment, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) // Code to be executed only in Production
                  &&
                    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(envRole) && envRole.ToLower().Contains(Constants.Role.Indexing.ToLower()) //Code to be executed only on CM side
                    )
                {

                    Log.SingleError("LinkDBRebuild job Method RebuildLinkDatabases. Getting Core Database", this);
                    Sitecore.Data.Database database = Factory.GetDatabase(Constants.Database.CoreDatabase);
                    Log.SingleError("LinkDBRebuild job Method RebuildLinkDatabases. Got Core Database. Rebuiliding it.", this);
                    RebuildLinkDatabase(database);
                    Log.SingleError("LinkDBRebuild job Method RebuildLinkDatabases. Core Database. Rebuilid success.", this);


                    Log.SingleError("LinkDBRebuild job Method RebuildLinkDatabases. Getting Master Database", this);
                    database = Factory.GetDatabase(Constants.Database.MasterDatabase);
                    Log.SingleError("LinkDBRebuild job Method RebuildLinkDatabases. Got Master Database. Rebuiliding it.", this);
                    RebuildLinkDatabase(database);
                    Log.SingleError("LinkDBRebuild job Method RebuildLinkDatabases. Master Database. Rebuilid success.", this);

                }
                else
                {
                    Log.SingleError("LinkDBRebuild job Method RebuildLinkDatabases. Either the environment is non-prod or the role is not CM", this);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.SingleError("LinkDBRebuild job Method RebuildLinkDatabases failed. Exception:" + ex.Message + "  Trace:" + ex.StackTrace, this);
            }
            Log.SingleError("LinkDBRebuild job completed succesfully from the custom code.", this);
        }

It has been working quite well for sometime. Recently we have noticed that that first 2 entries get logged.
Log.Info("LinkDBRebuild job triggered from custom code.", this);
Log.Info("LinkDBRebuild job triggered from custom code. Details: Env:" + envName + " Role: " + envRole, this);

After this, we do not see any entry from inside if or inside else.
From /sitecore/admin/jobs.aspx, we see the code is running for more than 22 hours, as expected.

So, please help me to understand the following:

what is happening here?
On jobs.aspx, why I am getting Master_Database_Agent not the scheduled command?


Did you restart your application and tried executing the same?

It is in Production. So cannot restart easily. Though it gets re-started after every 21 days minimum.

Ok then I would suggest you to create an aspx file to stop the current jobs using the solution in the below URL : https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5599/i-have-a-stuck-sitecore-jobs-job-now-how-do-i-kill-that
You can upload the file using Package installation wizard and since its aspx file it wont restart the instance.
And then restart the job again.

Looking at your code, I can see that the two lines that you can see in your logs every time are output using Log.Info().
For some reason, you have then switched to Log.SingleError() inside the If/Else block. Even though these still appear to be information type logs and not errors.
I did a quick search on SingleError() and various sites imply

Write an error message to the log, but write it one time only.

Ref: https://colddata.com/writing-to-sitecore-general-log/ (I couldnt find direct sitecore reference)
But based, on that, I suspect that if your instance has been running uninterupted for some time, then the missing logs were output one time several days ago, then are not logged again on subsequent runs.
Solution: Switch the logging inside If/Else to Log.Info().
